# Error LNK1181 while installing mysqlclient

Tags: python-3.x, pip

System Windows 10. Python 3.5. VS 2015 installed.

Got this error after fixing "unable to find vcvarsall.bat" Error. I don't know what to do with all this stuff. Please help.

```
Error log :
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.7.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: started
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command c:\python3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Yuriy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-wq1amnk2\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Yuriy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-t5ht7lva-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,3,7,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.7 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -Ic:\python3\include -Ic:\python3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
    _mysql.c
    _mysql.c(1461): warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(346): note:  ??. ?????????? "strncpy"
    _mysql.c(1463): warning C4996: 'strncat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncat_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(255): note:  ??. ?????????? "strncat"
    _mysql.c(1465): warning C4996: 'strncat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncat_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(255): note:  ??. ?????????? "strncat"
    _mysql.c(1499): warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(346): note:  ??. ?????????? "strncpy"
    _mysql.c(1501): warning C4996: 'strncat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncat_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(255): note:  ??. ?????????? "strncat"
    _mysql.c(1504): warning C4996: 'strncat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncat_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\string.h(255): note:  ??. ?????????? "strncat"
    _mysql.c(2236): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1769): note:  ??. ?????????? "sprintf"
    _mysql.c(2240): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1769): note:  ??. ?????????? "sprintf"
    _mysql.c(2316): warning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1769): note:  ??. ?????????? "sprintf"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib\vs14" /LIBPATH:c:\python3\libs /LIBPATH:c:\python3\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x86" kernel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib mysqlclient.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__mysql build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.5\_mysql.cp35-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\_mysql.cp35-win32.lib /MANIFEST
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181:
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181

    ----------------------------------------
```

If you need any more info, fill free to ask,
Thanks

Comment: Don't act helpless.  Put `fatal error LNK1181` in a search box and hit return.  Start with the Stackoverflow box above if you want, and you should get at least two questions.  However, using pre-build binaries for windows is better if possible.  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ has 3.4 binaries for mysqlclient.  There are compiled 3.5 binaries for most other libraries.  Perhaps there is no 3.5 binary for this library because compile-on-windows expert Christoff Gohlke could not get this one to compile.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy 1)" Put fatal error LNK1181 in a search box and hit return."
Already done. It usually comes with the name of a file. In my case, there is no file. 2) There is no package for 3.5.1 Python